A book about a witches school and a foundling. The baby's first tears are caught and they're an important element in a later spell
Two witches (teachers at a witches' school), discover a baby girl on the doorstep of the school. The baby's first tears are an important element of a potion that, years later will (?) save the life of one of the witches. It also has an a stuffed alligator on top of a cupboard — so I think it was illustrated in a British children's book style (i.e. pen and ink drawings).
I read this in 2001.
